# Command .removeEditors is not removing all editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I'm having an issue where when I remove editors from a document it is not removing all editors.  I am the owner of the spreadsheet. In the example below, I have a spreadsheet that is a work ticket for our jobs.  I want to restrict who can edit/access it once the job is closed to two individuals (example1@email.com and example2@email.com).

At the moment I am (probably inefficiently) removing all editors, and then re-adding example 1 and 2 on some sheets. This works.  On sheets that are providing references for the document that I do not want people to edit, I remove all editors and do not add any users back, it leaves me able to edit the sheet as the owner of the document. This also works.

However, the script is allowing boss@email.com on some of the sheets intermittently. Boss@email.com is not on the list of people who are original editors that I am removing. As I have been testing this, I have seen boss@email.com change sheets it shows up on, from sheets that should be only me to sheets that should be me and example1 and example2.

Logger.log is showing Editors as example1@email.com, example2@email.com, employeeA@email.com, employeeB@email.com, employeeC@email.com, bossalt@email.com.  My boss's email actually isn't showing up on the log of users for the document.

How can I prevent this random email from showing up, and is there a more efficient way to do this?  I've been looking at the Google Apps Script documentation, and I've been looking on StackOverflow, but I can't see how this problem's coming about.

A note: This is part of a shared Google Drive that is available to many people in my business.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var formsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form");
var bomsheet = ss.getSheetByName("BOM");
var scriptsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Script Work");
var lookupsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Lookup");
var invtemp = ss.getSheetByName("Inv Temp");
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);

Logger.log("Users," + (ss.getEditors()))

formsheet.protect().removeEditors(ss.getEditors());
formsheet.protect().addEditors(["example1@gmail.com","example2@email.com"]);
bomsheet.protect().removeEditors(ss.getEditors());
bomsheet.protect().addEditors(["example1@gmail.com","example2@email.com"]);
scriptsheet.protect().removeEditors(ss.getEditors());
lookupsheet.protect().removeEditors(ss.getEditors());
invtemp.protect().removeEditors(ss.getEditors());
```

Comment: You say your approach to protect your sheet works. But then you say that acutaly it does not work because `Boss@email.com` still has access after being removed from editors.Can you please specify this? Also, is `Boss@email.com` just `editor` or `owner` of the spreadsheet?

Comment: It's working intermittently, and this extra e-mail keeps showing up when I can't figure out why.    I am the editor and the owner, but it's part of a shared documents folder that is shared by my business.  I'm going to add that note above.

Comment: What do you mean by the "email showing up"? When you remove somebody from the editors, he will still be viewer. So when he views the spreadsheet, his icon will still show up at the top riht of the spreadsheet, adn the cells on which he clicks will also show up - even on the sheets where he is viewer.